# App installation failed Error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, cocoapods

When I installed alamofire pod into my project and open workspace file and try to run project on iphone device it gives

[image]

I tried putting other pod in project, the project runs on device but when I put alamofire pod to podfile the same error comes ,
I tried this with 2-3 projects still the same response.
My device is iPhone 5s with os 10.3.3.
And by the way, the app runs on the simulator.
Signing Certificate is correct.

Comment: Try restarting xcode, i face this issue sometimes.

Comment: @Dev_Tandel I also face this issue, however the step you are showing will not work, I also make few cases for them but it was not solved.

Comment: May be there is something an internal error or some internal clashing, I have also used alamofire, but recently I have faced this issue, before it was working fine.

Comment: In pods project setting info tab  are you able to see alamofire on Configuration  on both release and debug ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding manually by following step it is working for me

1 Open up Terminal, cd into your top-level project directory, and run the following command "if" your project is not initialized as a git repository:

$ git init

Add Alamofire as a git submodule by running the following command:

$ git submodule add https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git

3.Open the new Alamofire folder, and drag the Alamofire.xcodeproj into the Project Navigator of your application's Xcode project.

4.It should appear nested underneath your application's blue project icon. Whether it is above or below all the other Xcode groups does not matter.

5.Select the Alamofire.xcodeproj in the Project Navigator and verify the deployment target matches that of your application target.

6.Next, select your application project in the Project Navigator (blue project icon) to navigate to the target configuration window and select the application target under the "Targets" heading in the sidebar.

7.In the tab bar at the top of that window, open the "General" panel.

8.Click on the + button under the "Embedded Binaries" section.

9.You will see two different Alamofire.xcodeproj folders each with two different versions of the Alamofire.framework nested inside a Products folder.

10.It does not matter which Products folder you choose from, but it does matter whether you choose the top or bottom Alamofire.framework.
Select the top Alamofire.framework for iOS and the bottom one for OS X.

11.You can verify which one you selected by inspecting the build log for your project. The build target for Alamofire will be listed as either Alamofire iOS, Alamofire macOS, Alamofire tvOS or Alamofire watchOS.
And that's it!

12.The Alamofire.framework is automagically added as a target dependency, linked framework and embedded framework in a copy files build phase which is all you need to build on the simulator and a device.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problen and all I had to do was select Product/Clean (or use the key combination Shift+Command+K) and Run again the project and it worked to me, I hope it will helpful to you